# Bundles MVC angularjs, error angular is not defined

Tags: .net, angularjs, model-view-controller, bundle

My application works fine but i want bundle all references .css and .js

Before i had defined my references in my **Layout.cshtml** like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="catanei">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Catanei</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/font-awesome")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/base-styles")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar-wrapper">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml")
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Menu.cshtml")}
        </div>
        <main id="page-content-wrapper" role="main" style="padding-left:45px; padding-right:10px;">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <!----------------START DEPENDENCIES ---------------------------- >
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery/jquery.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.custom.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Site.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/filter-table.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ng-table-to-csv-master/dist/ng-table-to-csv.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-chart.js/angular-chart.js")
    <!-- ----------------END DEPENDENCIES ---------------------------- -->
    <!-- ----------------START CATANEI MODULE---------------------------- -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/app.config.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/app.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/common/app.js")
    <!-- ----------------END CATANEI MODULE------------------------------ -->
</body>
```

And my angular application works fine.
**Now i want** bundle my .js files and i coding my **BundleConfig.cs** like that:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace catanei
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // Para obtener más información sobre Bundles, visite http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/base-styles").Include(
                "~/Scripts/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css",
                "~/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.css",
                "~/Content/Site.css",
                "~/Content/custom.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/font-awesome").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dependencies").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js",
                  "~/Scripts/Site.js",
                  "~/Scripts/filter-table.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-animate/angular-animate.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-aria/angular-aria.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-messages/angular-messages.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.js",
                  "~/Scripts/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/ng-table-to-csv-master/dist/ng-table-to-csv.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-chart.js/angular-chart.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/catanei-module").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/app/app.config.js",
                 "~/Scripts/app/app.js",
                 "~/Scripts/app/common/app.js"));

            // Enable optimisation based on web.config setting
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And my **Layout.cshtml before** like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="catanei">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Catanei</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/font-awesome")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/base-styles")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar-wrapper">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml")
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Menu.cshtml")}
        </div>
        <main id="page-content-wrapper" role="main" style="padding-left:45px; padding-right:10px;">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <!----------------START DEPENDENCIES ---------------------------- >
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery/jquery.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.custom.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Site.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/filter-table.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ng-table-to-csv-master/dist/ng-table-to-csv.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-chart.js/angular-chart.js")
    <!-- ----------------END DEPENDENCIES ---------------------------- -->
    <!-- ----------------START CATANEI MODULE---------------------------- -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/app.config.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/app.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/common/app.js")
    <!-- ----------------END CATANEI MODULE------------------------------ -->
</body>
```

If you want see my angular scripts **app.config.js** :

```js
+function () {
    "use strict";

    const cataneiRun = () => {
    };

    angular.module("catanei", [
          "ngSanitize",
          "ui.select",
          "ngAnimate",
          "ngAria",
          "ngMessages",
          "ngMaterial",
          "chart.js",
          "ui.bootstrap",
          "ngTableToCsv",
          "common",
      ]).run(cataneiRun);
}();
```

And my app.js:

```js
+ function () {
    "use strict";

    function cataneiConfig(
        $httpProvider,
        ChartJsProvider
    ) {
        ChartJsProvider.setOptions({ colors: ['#803690', '#00ADF9', '#DCDCDC', '#46BFBD', '#FDB45C', '#949FB1', '#4D5360'] });
    }
    cataneiConfig.$inject = [
        "$httpProvider",
        "ChartJsProvider"     
    ];
    angular
      .module("catanei")
      .config(cataneiConfig);
}();
```

**But obtain an error** of angular is not defined:
[Click see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P6PQ.png)

Comment: I think you just made a typo in your HTML comment: `<!-- START DEPENDENCIES----  >`  Should end like this: `<!-- START DEPENDECIES--- -->`. The way it is now, you are commenting out your dependencies!

Comment: Ok, but not resolve my problem